# How to display image in .twig file from .theme file upload

Tags: drupal

### How to display image in .twig file from .theme file upload

.theme file

```
 $form['third_logo'] = array(
'#title' => t('Footer Secondary logo'),
'#type' => 'managed_file',
'#upload_location' => 'public://secondary-logo/',
'#upload_validators' => array(
  'file_validate_extensions' => array('gif png jpg jpeg svg'),
),
'#default_value' => theme_get_setting('third_logo'),
```

);

.twig file

```
<img src="{{ third_logo }}" alt="acquia-logo" title="acquia-logo">
```

Comment: You need to include the relevant error messages or an example of how it is failing within your question, Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: there is no error......image is uploading....but i need to display ....so what is the way to write a code in .twig file

Comment: is this right?     <img src="{{ third_logo }}" alt="acquia-logo" title="acquia-logo">

Answer (score 0):

Rough outline as your question is too broad:

You need to store the image file ID or image file location in some variable (a settings value). You then need to get that value, load the image from that, wire it through a `theme()` function and let some `*_preprocess()` function return the output into its `$variables` array to then get hold of the markup to insert it into the template file.

I guess when you look through existing themes you might discover pretty fast how they store and how to print their logo. Copy their approach. You don't have to re-invent the wheel.